# Create a duplicate row based on a condition in MySQL (v8)

Tags: mysql

I need to add a condition to my query that duplicates a row based on a  condition.

**Example:**

```
Order_details:
order_id | Item | Qty | Packets
1        | A    | 5   | 5
1        | B    | 3   | 5
1        | C    | 3   | 2
2        | X    | 1   | 4
3        | Z    | 10  | 6
```

I want to check: **Total(Qty * Packets) > 20**

The output should look like this:

```
order_id | Item | Qty | Packets | Total |
1        | A    | 5   | 4       | 20    |
1_1      | A    | 5   | 1       | 5     |
1        | B    | 3   | 5       | 15    |
1        | C    | 3   | 2       | 6     |
2        | X    | 1   | 4       | 4     |
3        | Z    | 10  | 2       | 20    |
3_1      | Z    | 10  | 2       | 20    |
3_2      | Z    | 10  | 2       | 20    |
```

Is the operation described above possible?

Comment: (1) Imagine there is a row `(4, 'T', 13, 3)`. What will be the output? (2) Does `(order_id, item)` is defined as unique? *I am not sure if this is possible or not.* Be sure this is possible.

Comment: @Akina 
(1) `(4, 'T', 13, 1, 13), (4_1, 'T', 13, 1, 13), (4_2, 'T', 13, 1, 13)`
(2) `order_id` is unique

Comment: (1) Oops.. backward, for `(4, 'T', 3, 13)`. (2) ?? In sample data you show 3 rows with `order_id=1` - I doubt that this is "unique". *EDIT 1: MySQL version 5 and above.* Either 5 or 8. They're too different.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Akina
(1) `(4, 'T', 3, 6, 18), (4_1, 'T', 3, 6, 18), (4_2, 'T', 3, 1, 3)`
(2) As I mentioned that this is a part of an existing query, so the example table is actually a sample output of that query. So for now we can take `order_id` as not a unique value.
EDIT: Have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT order_id, 
                Item, 
                Qty,
                CASE WHEN Qty * Packets > 20
                     THEN 20 DIV Qty
                     ELSE Packets 
                     END Packets,
                Packets - CASE WHEN Qty * Packets > 20
                               THEN 20 DIV Qty
                               ELSE Packets 
                               END Rest
          FROM Order_details
        UNION ALL
          SELECT order_id, 
                Item, 
                Qty,
                CASE WHEN Qty * Rest > 20
                     THEN 20 DIV Qty
                     ELSE Rest 
                     END,
                Rest - CASE WHEN Qty * Rest > 20
                            THEN 20 DIV Qty
                            ELSE Rest 
                            END 
          FROM cte
          WHERE Rest > 0)
SELECT order_id, 
       Item, 
       Qty,
       Packets,
       Qty * Packets Total
FROM cte 
ORDER BY order_id, 
         Item,
         Packets DESC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a2f01e475d988fc8c41730d68cc96ed)

Answer (score 0):

Without mysql 8's recursive cte support, you need to pick some maximum number of duplicate rows to support.  This duplicates up to 9 times:

```
select
    if(suborder,concat(order_id,'_',suborder),order_id) order_id,
    item,
    qty,
    least(floor(20/qty),packets-suborder*floor(20/qty)) packets
from (select 0 suborder union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) suborder
join (
    # original non-duplicated query goes here
    select order_id, item, qty, packets
    from order_details
) od on ceil(packets/floor(20/qty)) > suborder
order by od.order_id,item,suborder
```

In mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2, you would do it like this:

```
with recursive od as (
    select order_id,item,qty,packets,0 suborder
    from (
        # original non-duplicated query goes here
        select order_id, item, qty, packets
        from order_details
    ) od
    union all
    select order_id,item,qty,packets-floor(20/qty),suborder+1
    from od where packets > floor(20/qty)
)
select if(suborder,concat(order_id,'_',suborder),order_id) order_id,
    item,
    qty,
    least(floor(20/qty),packets) packets
from od
order by od.order_id,item,suborder
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4483a3a91efaeccb7fe596020bff2bf4)